# Give a Conditional SUM on spesifict product or Item

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this

```
Product Quantity
a          2
b          3
c          4
d          1
e          5
```

I wondering how to sum specific products like c, d, and e.
Me already trying this

```
SELECT sum(quantity)
  FROM product
 where product.product in ('a', 'b')
 group by product
UNION
select sum(quantity)
  from product
 where product.product IN ('c', 'd', 'e')
```

But I can't display the name of the product, the end of results should like this

```
Product     Quantity
a              2
b              3
sum(c,d,e)   (4+1+5)
```

Comment: So, you want to create subsets of products (some of them have only one element, but that is not relevant), and sum over such subsets. Where/how do you store information about which products are in which subset? A common way would be a small lookup table, showing product and which subset it belongs to. If so, then you would join the two tables, and group by "subset" column from the second table.

Comment: solving the problem , using subquery ```select product, sum(quantity) value
  from (select case
                 when a.product not in ('a', 'b') then
                  'Other''s Product'
                 else
                  a.product
               end product,
               a.quantity quantity,
               case
                 when a.product not in ('a', 'b') then
                  'sum'
               end validasi
          from product a)
 group by validasi, product ```

Comment: Oh - so products `a` and `c` are special, and the rest are in the "other" category? Do you need to hard-code `a` and `c` in the query, or are they given by the user at runtime, or where else do they come from? And, in the output, do you want the "names" of all the other products (`b, d, e`) to appear in the first column, as in the output you show? It can be done, it just looks odd (and, with longer product names, the string may simply be too long).

Comment: yap, me consider about the performance of this query, maybe this is a temp solution for me , the product itself I can make that as a parameter input (dynamic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CASE** statement to group your specific items . You can add multiple group if you want. You don't need subquery.

```
select CASE WHEN ProductName IN ('c','d','e') THEN 'bde' ELSE  ProductName END,
SUM(Quentity) from product
group by CASE WHEN ProductName IN ('c','d','e') THEN 'bde' ELSE  ProductName END
;
```

Comment: ah , forgot add case when on group by , thanks , this works as well